# Change Slider Vertical Handle to Image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I'm using jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css and I tried to change the slider handle into image.

It works when I use following CSS and HTML.

**CSS:**

```
.slider-basic .ui-slider-handle {
   width:50;
   height: 50;
   background: url(images/slider/50x50.png) no-repeat;
   border: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <div class="slider slider-basic bg-red"></div>
</html>
```

But I need to change my slider into vertical, so the HTML becomes

```
<div id="slider-vertical" class="slider bg-green"></div>
```

and the CSS does not seem to work at all. Could you please help me find out why?

Comment: please share you css too

Comment: You use the class `.slider-basic .ui-slider-handle` but I don't see that in your HTML, does that get loaded on the fly by `JQuery UI`?

Comment: I changed the .slider-basic to .slider-vertical... but nothing happened. I wonder which code I should change

Comment: the css other than that is jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css

Comment: The CSS would need to be `#slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle` as the selector since you're using an ID and not a class.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is like so:

```
<div id="slider-vertical" class="slider bg-green"></div>
```

You'd want the following CSS:

```
#slider-vertical .ui-slider-handle {
   background: url(images/slider/50x50.png) no-repeat;
   border: none;
}
```

In your previous HTML you set the class. In this new HTML, you set the ID.